# Multiple reports from a single xml file (xml datasource)

Tags: birt

I'm currently evaluating BIRT and trying to understand how everything works.

I'd like to **render multiple reports** (PDFs) **from a single XML** file
This xml contains the data required for all reports/PDFs.

**Each report** should be **mapped** with the data from a **specific node in the XML DOM tree** of the file.
How can I archive this?

Comment: I don't know what 'specific node in the DOM tree' means, I use the shareware version of BIRT and it is very easy to create mulitple reports (i.e. Tables, graphs, lists, etc) on a single report.  You just keep dropping new  report items on the report.  They can use shared or independent parameters. You can also insert page breaks to ensure that when they print out as single PDF document each "report" starts on its own page.

Comment: With "A single report" I mean "a single PDF" file. So what I have is one single XML file containing the data of 10000 reports, and I want to create 10000 PDFs out of it. I want to know how I can "tell" the report engine which node (part) of the XML file (e.g. by XPath) it should use in the current iteration for binding the data to the template in order to create the specific PDF out of it.

Comment: Sorry, that is out of my skill set. If you don't get an answer here, try http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/index

Comment: A simular question with a partial answer is here. http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/forum/index.php/topic/29581-output-separate-pdf-files-for-each-group/